# Extending the Exception class in Dart

Tags: dart

I keep getting an error when I try to extend the Exception class and can't figure out why.
Here is the code for my custom exception:

```dart
class MyException extends Exception {
  String msg;
  MyException(this.msg);
  String toString() => 'FooException: $msg';
}
```

The error resolves around the constructor. It complains that "The generative constructor 'Exception([dynamic message]) -> Exception' expected, but factory found". How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot extend a class defining just a factory constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564676/extending-a-class-with-only-one-factory-constructor

Answer (score 54):

You have it almost right. You need to *implement* Exception rather than extend it. This should work:

```dart
class MyException implements Exception {
  final String msg;
  const MyException(this.msg);
  String toString() => 'FooException: $msg';
}
```

You don't have to make `msg` final or the constructor `const`, but you can. Here is an example of an implementation of the Exception class (from the dart:core library):

```dart
class FormatException implements Exception {
  /**
   * A message describing the format error.
   */
  final String message;

  /**
   * Creates a new FormatException with an optional error [message].
   */
  const FormatException([this.message = ""]);

  String toString() => "FormatException: $message";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to the other answer: more than a message string, it'd be useful to have a `type` or `code` so the invoker can decide what to do based on the exception type. For example:

```dart
enum NfcErrorType { communication, parse, timeout, mismatch }

class NfcException implements Exception {
  final NfcErrorType type;

  NfcException(this.type);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'NfcException: $type';
  }
}
```

Then you can throw like:

```dart
throw NfcException(NfcErrorType.parse);
```

And the invoker can catch this way:

```dart
try {
  // ...
} on NfcException catch (err) {
  switch(err.type) {
    case NfcErrorType.parse:
      // do something
      break;
    case NfcErrorType.communication:
      // do something different
      break;
    // .... other cases

  }
} catch(err) {
  // handle some other way...
}
```

Comment: In recent Dart versions, you could also use a sealed class with inheriting subclasses to achieve this.