# How to write abstract class constructors so that it will be flexible for extending in sub classes

Tags: dart, language-design

I am trying to implement a persistent `Stack` data structure. I want to implement this as an algebraic data type, so it has two concrete subtypes: *empty* and *non empty*:

```dart
abstract class Stack<T> {
  factory Stack.empty() => const _EmptyStack._();

  T get data;
  Stack<T> get bottom;
  bool get isEmpty;
  Stack<T> put(T item) => new _StackImpl(item, this);
}

class _StackImpl<T> extends Stack<T> {
  final T _data;
  final Stack<T> _bottom;

  _StackImpl(T this._data, Stack<T> this._bottom);

  T get data => _data;
  Stack<T> get bottom => _bottom;
  bool get isEmpty => false;
}

class _EmptyStack<T> extends Stack<T> {
  const _EmptyStack._();
  T get data => throw new CollectionIsEmpty();
  Stack<T> get bottom => throw new CollectionIsEmpty();
  bool get isEmpty => true;
}
```

This code raises two errors in concrete implementations:

```dart
[error] The class 'Stack' does not have a default generative constructor
```

I found a sample code which seem to [address this problem here](https://github.com/mitsuoka/dart_code_samples/blob/f9ac143475aa78fbdd5b5aafc87927864f124ee2/codes/code_05.7a.dart), so I've fixed it by putting a parameterless constructor in `Stack<T>` class:

```dart
abstract class Stack<T> {
    Stack();
    // ...
```

but now this causes problem with `_EmptyStack<T>` constructor, which is constant:

```dart
Constant constructor cannot call non-constant super constructor of 'Stack<T>'
```

Additionally the added `Stack()` constructor prevents from using the class as a mixin.

These restrictions seem to enforce on the class author to think about how the class would be extended. [The way of extending `List` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247045/how-do-i-extend-a-list-in-dart) from `dart:collection` package seem to confirm this conclusion - there is an entire separate class to use for extension, I can't directly extend the `List` class itself.

My question is more general then the problem described above: how can I write a class so that it can be flexible enough to extend? That includes allowing the use of features like:

1. factory constructors in super class
2. *normal* constructors in sub class
3. `const` constructors in sub class
4. be used as a mixin

While I understand that the use as mixin might be impossible or even unwanted, other points are still valid. Most importantly the question stands: why can't I `extend` a class with a factory constructor? This is a behavior unlike any other OO language I'm familiar with.

Also related questions:

- [Extending a class with only one factory constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564676/extending-a-class-with-only-one-factory-constructor)
- [Extending the Exception class in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096470/extending-the-exception-class-in-dart)

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Günter Zöchbauer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700608/1697320) I've improved the code, so now it is fully operational (see below). The most important question that I am now left with is: why factory constructor breaks the ability to extend the class? And how to get around it (aside from using the base class as interface)? A simpler example to make the point:

```dart
class Base {
}

class _Sub extends Base {
  int someValue;
  _Sub(int this.someValue);
}
```

Everything is fine with this code. But let's say I get back to my `Base` class in time and want to add factory method:

```dart
class Base {
    factory Base.empty() => new _Sub(0);
}
```

Now each class which extends `Base` is broken because of `unresolved implicit call to super constructor`. What do I do then?

Corrected code from original question for reference:

```dart
abstract class Stack<T> {
  const Stack._();
  factory Stack.empty() => const _EmptyStack._();

  T get data;
  Stack<T> get bottom;
  bool get isEmpty;
  Stack<T> put(T item) => new _StackImpl(item, this);
}

class _StackImpl<T> extends Stack<T> {
  final T _data;
  final Stack<T> _bottom;

  _StackImpl(T this._data, Stack<T> this._bottom) : super._();

  T get data => _data;
  Stack<T> get bottom => _bottom;
  bool get isEmpty => false;
}

class _EmptyStack<T> extends Stack<T> {
  const _EmptyStack._() : super._();
  T get data => throw new CollectionIsEmpty();
  Stack<T> get bottom => throw new CollectionIsEmpty();
  bool get isEmpty => true;
}

void main(){

  group('stack', (){

    test('empty stack', (){
      var emptyStack = new Stack.empty();
      expect(emptyStack.isEmpty, isTrue);
      expect(() => emptyStack.data, throwsA(new isInstanceOf<CollectionIsEmpty>()));
      expect(() => emptyStack.bottom, throwsA(new isInstanceOf<CollectionIsEmpty>()));

      var emptyStack2 = new Stack.empty();
      expect(emptyStack == emptyStack2, isTrue);
    });

    test('adding to stack', (){

      var stack = new Stack<String>.empty().put("a").put("b").put("c");

      expect(stack.data, equals('c'));
      expect(stack.bottom.data, equals('b'));
      expect(stack.bottom.bottom.data, equals('a'));

    });

  });

}
```

Comment: @GameAlchemist The design is a fundamental principle of functional programing and it does work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10045677/1697320) for more insight on the subject. Additionally: as I have stated my question is more general then this particular case. It is only an example.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I suggest to just use `Stack` as an interface instead of a base class.

1. factory constructors in super class
   If you have a factory constructor you have to add a normal constructor too if you want to extend as stated in the answer to the linked question.
2. normal constructors in sub class
   What was the actual question here? I guess this is the same as 1.
3. const constructors in sub class
   If you want a const constructor all subclasses need to have a const constructor too.
   In a class with a const constructor all fields need to be final. This isn't the case with your base class so where is the point of adding a const constructor to `_EmptyStack`.
4. be used as a mixin
   The restrictions for classes to be used as a mixin are temporary and should be removed at some point.

Comment: The interface solution is not good enough. Why would I have to reimplement each non-abstract methods (DRY)? What if the _interface_ gets a new method with body in time? I would have to find all it's implementations and correct it. This wouldn't be the case with abstract class. Please see my update to the question.

Comment: Ad 2 - ok I got little confused, somehow I thought that having `const Stack()` constructor would prevent me from having non-const `_StackImpl()` constructor, but it worked (see update). Ad 3 - what do you mean not all fields are final? There are only two fields in `_StackImpl<T>` and they are both final. Base class has no fields, only abstract getters. Do they count as non-final fields?

Comment: Sorry this was an oversight. I missed that these are just getters.